# What is a $p$-adic analytic variety?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I can't find the definition, or any references. The term doesn't seem to appear much in the literature. I would imagine that you just replace $\mathbb{C}$ with a local field, but it's strange that I can't find any places where this is discussed. I know that in Serre's Lie Algebras and Lie Groups, he discusses $p$-adic manifolds, but where can I find a reference on analytic varieties over local fields? I mean $p$-adic analytic variety as used in p.166 of this paper by Barry Mazur: http://www.raco.cat/index.php/CollectaneaMathematica/article/viewFile/56382/66675

Comment: Try looking for "Tate algebras", "affinoids", and "rigid analytic space". Also, have a look here: http://math.arizona.edu/~cais/scans/BGR-Non_Archimedean_Analysis.pdf

Comment: You might also find [Kiran Kedlaya's course notes on rigid analytic geometry](http://kskedlaya.org/18.727/) helpful.

Comment: So, is there a notion of analytic variety other than rigid analytic variety? I'm just not sure if that is the kind of variety that Mazur is referring to.

Comment: @CoffeeBliss I'm pretty sure that he just means here a $p$-adic analytic manifold. Which is, as you might imagine, a locally ringed space locally isomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbb{Q}_p^n$ with the sheaf of locally analytic functions.